# how is the following expressions **2.0+"2"** evaluated step by step in Java? and how is it different from **2+"2"**?

Tags: java, string, types, casting, addition

in java a number is automatically converted into a string ,hence **2+"2"** evaluates to 22...
but why does  **2.0+"2"** evaluates to 2.02..

Here's where i m learning from

https://www.coursera.org/learn/cs-programming-java/lecture/o5IxV/type-conversion

Comment: Because 2.0 is different from 2?

Answer (score 3):

When you concatenate anything with a `String`, the thing that isn't a `String` must be converted to one. So `2.0+"2"` is `"2.0" + "2"` and `2+"2"` is `"2"+"2"`.